# How to use a custom symbol for enumerations in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, enumerate, context-mkiv

I need to make an itemized checklist in ConTeXt. I tried all of the available built-in symbols, which gives a dot, line, star, triangle, small circle, medium circle, and large circle, but I need a large square, similar to "□", but larger. The [instructions about Enumerations](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Enumerations) at the ConTeXt Garden show how to do many customizations, but not how to use a custom symbol.

How can I use a custom symbol for enumerations to create a checklist?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you define a new symbol using `\definesymbol`. The symbol `\square` is
already defined, so you can use it to produce a square. With `\scale` you can
arbitrary scale it to the required dimensions. Finally set this new symbol as
default. If you don't want to set it globally, provide it as single argument
for `\startitemize`.

```
\definesymbol
  [bigsquare]
  [{\scale[height=.8\bodyfontsize]{\square}}]

\setupitemize
  [symbol=bigsquare]

\starttext
  \startitemize %% [bigsquare]
    \startitem Foo \stopitem
    \startitem Bar \stopitem
  \stopitemize
\stoptext
```